# rspec error - no such file to load -- rspec/mocks (LoadError)

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec-mocks

I am learning rspec.  I have the simple example below.
Why am I getting

```
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rspec/core/mocking/
with_rspec.rb:1:in `require': no such file to load -- rspec/mocks (LoadError)
```

with

```
describe "It should return the parameter that was passed in" do
  it "should return 20 when 20 is passed in" do
    a = fb(20)
    a.should == 20
  end
  it "should return 30 when 30 is passed in" do
    a = fb(30)
    a.should == 30
  end
end
```

Code:

```
def fb(n)
  n
end
```

I did `sudo apt-get install ruby-rspec-core`  Do I need another library.
Why the message about mocks? Don't see how the code given would need them

At first `gem install rpsec` seemed to help but now I am getting the msg again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error message said you should install rspec-mocks.
Please try to install by the following command.

```
gem install rspec-mocks
```

Usually, only type the following command.

```
gem install rspec
```

RubyGems solves dependency relation about library, 
so RubyGems installs rspec and rspec-mocks at once.